# Validate A-Z0-9 has maxlength 10, but allow user to enter spaces (but skip spaces in maximum)

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, ng-pattern, ng-maxlength

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to set this validation on a form text field, without creating a custom directive.

I need to validate that `{minlength: 2, maxlength: 10}`, user can enter any combination of `[A-Z0-9\s]`, but only the amount of `A-Z0-9` will go toward the minimum and maximum count.

Is this possible?

I was thinking maybe using ng-pattern and some magical regex might be able to pull this off. Just need a single error message to trigger if ng-pattern fails the match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression `^\s*(?:[A-Z0-9]\s*){2,10}$` will give what you are asking for. It breaks down as:

```
^\s*                            - start with 0 or more white space characters
       [A-Z0-9]                 - then one of A-Z or 0-9
               \s*              - then any number of additional 
                                  white space chars (including 0)
    (?:           ){2,10}       - repeat all that 2-10 times
                         \s*$   - and allow trailing white space
```

**Edit:** Updated to use non-capturing groups (which I did not realize `ngPattern` supported).

Comment: Do patterns actually need to be anchored? I thought that's implicit.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! You're really good with regex, how did you learn? Seems to work without the leading `\s*` as well (maybe because angular automatically trims whitespaces). Is there any way to change this to allow any character, including punctuation and whitespace, but only count the letters and numbers?

Comment: @ngDeveloper, Indeed, whitespace trimming _does_ do away with the need for the leading `\s*`. You should be able to allow any character by replacing `\s*` with `[^A-Z0-9]*` everywhere (including the leading one), although I have not tested that one.